# How do I select random from a table 25 questions from each categories,I have 4 categories?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with questions, i want to select random from each category 25 questions.

The table "questions" looks like that:

The categories are: C PC P PP

id question category answer1 answer2 answer3

Comment: 25 from each? So a total of 100?

Comment: Would it be time to take this frequent question into Community Wiki?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `union all` with a subquery for each category:

```
(select * from questions where category = 'C' order by rand() limit 25)
union all
(select * from questions where category = 'PC' order by rand() limit 25)
union all
(select * from questions where category = 'P' order by rand() limit 25)
union all
(select * from questions where category = 'PP' order by rand() limit 25)
```

If you have a lot of categories or a whole lot of questions (hundreds of thousands or more), then you might want a query that performs better.  But for lesser amounts of data, this is probably fine.

I want to emphasize that `union all` is better for such a query than `union`.  `union` removes duplicates adding addition processing that should not be needed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by `i want to select random from each category` but you can just fetch 25 question from each category and union them like

```
select question from sometable where category = 'C' limit 25
union
select question from sometable where category = 'PC' limit 25
union
select question from sometable where category = 'P' limit 25
union
select question from sometable where category = 'PP' limit 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Used an outer query with `ORDER BY RAND()` to select records which are selected from the inner query in a random fashion.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='C' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25) T1
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='PC' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25) T2
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='P' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25) T3
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM questions WHERE category='PP' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25) T4
) TT
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `HINT` you can work upon.

**SYNTAX:**
*Use this query :*

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` )
```

In place of `'table'` put `'questions'`.(This is because you have a table name 'questions').

Hope this will help.